# How to Conditionally Inject Dependencies into Services based on their type in .NET 6?

Tags: c#, asp.net, dependency-injection

I got a C# gRPC sln with .NET 6 (not sure if the fact that its grpc matters for this question) with 2 different C# classes which are implemeting the logic of 2 different grpc services which derives from 2 different services defined in 2 different proto files:

```
public class MyServiceV2 : My_Service.My_ServiceBase
public class MyServiceV3 : My_Service_V3.My_Service_V3Base
```

These 2 services run side by side at the same time and registered their endpoint.

Both these classes have a constructor with `ClassA` as a parameter.
There are also derived classes from `ClassA`:

```
public class ClassAV2 : ClassA
public class ClassAV3 : ClassA
```

How can I make the DI in the startup file such that `MyServiceV2` will be injected with `ClassAV2` in the constructor for the `ClassA` parameter, while `MyServiceV3` will be injected with `ClassAV3`?

Note: The services can't have the parameter as the actual class since there is a different behavior for prod env and non prod env: in prod env the it should be as I wrote above, but for non prod env the parameter should be injected with the base `ClassA` only. I know how to tell between prod and non prod env, just not how to inject to a specific service when in prod env.

Adding pseudo code to what I want to achieve:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    if(InProduction()) //already got this
    {
       services.FindService(typeof(MyServiceV2)).AddSingleton<ClassA, ClassAV2>();
    services.FindService(typeof(MyServiceV3)).AddSingleton<ClassA, ClassAV3>();
    }
    else
    {
       services.AddSingleton<ClassA>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why can't the constructors of the actual classes simply take the actual types instead of the base type?

Comment: Indeed, if you want a specific type why not use *that* type instead of the interface? The `why` matters: if you really need to distinguish between implementations of the same service you can use the [keyed services](https://andrewlock.net/exploring-the-dotnet-8-preview-keyed-services-dependency-injection-support/) introduced in .NET 8. Andrew Lock's article shows a valid example - you want an INotificationService for "SMS" but don't care about the *actual* implementation, so you don't want to hard-code the type

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos edited the question explaining why

Comment: Also, I'm using .net 6

Comment: Not really. You can register different service in production or development and keep using the interfaces

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand what you mean.. both services have to run side by side both in prod or non prod env, but the class which injected needs to be changed according to the environment and service

Comment: Production and development environments aren't "side-by-side. When you start your application the content of the `DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` or `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT` environment variables determines whether the application runs in production or development and controls which `appsettings` file is loaded. You can use the contents of that env variable to register different services in production and development.

Comment: At the spot in code where you register the service you know if you are in production or development?

Comment: `injected with the base ClassA only` that's where the problem starts. Not only can't you tell between production and development, you can't even tell whether you need `ClassAV2` or `ClassAV3`. If the two services need different types, use two different interfaces.

Comment: In .NET 8 you could use keyed services and use different `FromKeyedServices` keys in the two services, but it's unclear from these made-up names if this would be a good choice or just cover up the missing interfaces. Only you know what the actual services and classes do

Comment: For me it sound that its a matter of registering ClassA correctly. In one environment register ClassAV2 for ClassA and in the other ClassAV3 for ClassA or i'm still missing enough context in the question to really understand the problem.

Comment: Not the envs run side by side but the grpc services themselves run side by side with 2 different endpoints and I just need to inject the v2 service with the v2 class and the same with v3 and v3 class. As I said - I CAN know when Im in production and when im not. I just need to inject then to a specific service the specific class.

Comment: So different environments doesn't mean different instances of this system (as i would have suspected by its name) but just different endpoint to the system but with the same (more or less) backing services then that need to behave differently according to the endpoint used?

Comment: I added a pseudo code to show what I meant I need

Comment: @Ralf in this case, a prod env meaning the service is running in an AKS cluster, while a non prod env is the service running in a regular local docker compose environment or simply from Visual Studio directly, but like I said, I know how to make the difference in the code for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I eventually did was using a factory.

```
public class MyFactory
{
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    public MyFactory(IServiceProvider serviceProvider) 
    { 
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
    }

    public ClassA GetClassA(ServiceVersion serviceVersion, bool isForProduction)
    {                 
        if(isForProduction) 
        {
            switch(serviceVersion)
            {
                case ServiceVersion.V2:
                {
                     return new CLassAV2( _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyInterface>());
                }
                case ServiceVersion.V3:
                {
                     return new CLassAV3( _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<IMyInterface>());
                }
                default:
                {
                    throw new NotImplementedException("Unsupported service version");
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            switch (serviceVersion)
            {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then:

1. made a DI for the factory in the startup file
2. changed the services themselves to have `MyFactory` as a parameter to their constructor.
3. invoked the factory's GetClassA method from the constructor to initialize the correct type for the service

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick for you:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    bool isProd = InProduction();

    services.AddSingleton<ClassA>();
    services.AddSingleton<ClassAV2>();
    services.AddSingleton<ClassAV3>();

    services.AddTransient<MyServiceV2>(sp =>
        ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyServiceV2>(
            isProd
                ? sp.GetRequiredService<ClassAV2>()
                : sp.GetRequiredService<ClassA>()));

    services.AddTransient<MyServiceV3>(sp =>
        ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyServiceV3>(
            isProd
                ? sp.GetRequiredService<ClassAV3>()
                : sp.GetRequiredService<ClassA>()));
}
```

Comment: Why were the services themselves were added as transient and not scoped? If the services represent a grpc service, then I would expect everything to be the same for the same request

Comment: I guessed the lifestyle; adapt the code accordingly to your needs.

Comment: BTW, I'm not really that knowledgeable with DI... Aren't you supposed to make a DI using calls like AddTransient for a class/interface which are a parameter in a constructor of another class? Since MyServiceV2 and MyServiceV3 are standalone classes and are only registered as a grpc endpoint

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your question; I'm unable to answer.