# Making a factory method to return a singleton service from DI

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, singleton

I got a .NET6 C# factory class with a get method:

```
public MyClass GetMyClass(bool condition)
{
    return new MyClass(condition ? sp.GetRequiredService<IMyInterface1>() : sp.GetRequiredService<IMyInterface2>()
}
```

The factory itself is injected to a service as a singleton and the `GetMyClass` method is being called in its constructor.

The issue is that the service itself is scoped, which makes `MyClass` be scoped as well since its created every time the service is created. I would like to change the Get method to return a singleton object, and I like it to be by retrieving it from the service provider.

The problem with this is that in order to that, I need to inject 2 instances of `MyClass` before that as singletons, but I don't know how to get the correct one and not even sure if calling `AddSingleton` on the same type twice with a different parameter to the ctr even creates a second instance or if it just overrides the first one.

I know I can probably do a standard singleton pattern with properties in the factory but I want to first check if it can be done with DI for consistency.

Comment: You need *2 instances* of a *singleton*? Do you see the contradiction? You may also want to specify what DI container you use. I know unity container support both named registrations and child containers that allow all kinds of funky stuff to be done, but it seem to be defunct now.

Comment: @JonasH based on [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77825533/how-to-conditionally-inject-dependencies-into-services-based-on-their-type-in-n), OP is on Microsoft DI with < .Net 8

Comment: Yes I do need 2 instances of a singleton since each is meant for a different service. The singleton is only at the scope of the service itself, not at the scope of the entire program. It's a grpc service with Microsoft DI implemented using .net 6

Comment: Can't you just create two wrapper classes, which will extend MyClass and then add these two wrapper classes as Singleton into the ServiceCollection. Then you should be able to get them in your Factory Class and return them as MyClass

Comment: @TheTanic That's a nice idea if I don't find other ways of doing it